# Использование вложенных Media queries css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Подскажите пожалуйста, корректно ли использовать медиа запросы таким образом?Вроде все работает, но смущает правильность использования вложенных запросов.Спасибо!

```
@media all and (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 480px){
    @media all and (orientation: portrait){
           .header{
               visibility: hidden;
           }
       }
    @media all and (orientation: landscape){
        .header {
            color: #6ABD97;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 320 на 480 , это для какого девайса вёрстка ?

Comment: А зачем у вас стоит ограничение по максимальной ширине?

Comment: Было [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668301/is-it-possible-to-nest-media-queries-within-media-queries)